# Same stored procedure, same tables, different DB gives different result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have stored procedure which gives me expected result when I run it on MySQL 5. But when I tried to run same procedure on MariaDB 10.1.22, it gives me a different result.

Here is my stored procedure -

```
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE DEFINER=`mconnect_admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `TestCumulative`(IN 
    start_date TIMESTAMP,IN end_date TIMESTAMP,IN duration TEXT,IN 
    mno_id TEXT,IN profile_type TEXT,IN timezone TEXT)

    BEGIN
    SET @provisioned = 0;
    SET @downloaded = 0;

    SET @excludeProfileFilter = FALSE;
    SET @hourlyReport = FALSE;
    SET @monthlyReport = FALSE;
    SET @sdate = start_date;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempDates;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempDates(timeRange 
    VARCHAR(50));
    DELETE FROM tempDates;

    IF(profile_type = '')
       THEN
       SET profile_type = null;
       SET @excludeProfileFilter = TRUE;
    END IF;

    IF (duration = 'lastDay')
      THEN
      SET @hourlyReport=true;
    END IF;

    IF (duration = 'lastYear')
      THEN
      SET @monthlyReport = TRUE;
    END IF;

    WHILE @sdate <= end_date DO
       IF (@hourlyReport = TRUE)
         THEN
         INSERT INTO tempDates (timeRange) VALUES (HOUR(@sdate) + 1);
         SET @sdate = date_add(@sdate, INTERVAL 1 HOUR); 
       ELSE IF(@monthlyReport = TRUE)
         THEN
         INSERT INTO tempDates (timeRange) VALUES (MONTH(@sdate));
         SET @sdate = date_add(@sdate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
       ELSE
         INSERT INTO tempDates (timeRange) VALUES (DATE(@sdate));
         SET @sdate = date_add(@sdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
       END IF;
       END IF;
   END WHILE ;

   SELECT  CASE WHEN r.DateRange IS NULL THEN (@provisioned := 
   @provisioned) ELSE (@provisioned := @provisioned + r.Provisioned) 
   END AS Provisioned,
   CASE WHEN r.DateRange IS NULL THEN (@downloaded := @downloaded) ELSE 
   (@downloaded := @downloaded + r.Downloaded) END AS Downloaded, 
   CASE WHEN r.DateRange IS NULL THEN d.timeRange ELSE r.DateRange END 
   AS DateRange FROM (
   SELECT sum(result.Provisioned) as Provisioned, 
   sum(result.Downloaded) AS Downloaded, result.DateRange FROM (

   SELECT 
   1 As Provisioned, 
   0 AS Downloaded,
   CASE WHEN @hourlyReport=TRUE 
        THEN HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(s.provisioning_date,"+00:00",timezone)) 
        WHEN @monthlyReport=TRUE
        THEN MONTH(CONVERT_TZ(s.provisioning_date,"+00:00",timezone)) 
        ELSE DATE(CONVERT_TZ(s.provisioning_date,"+00:00",timezone))
    END     
    AS DateRange 

   FROM subscription s 
   INNER JOIN profile_type p ON p.id = s.profile_type 
   WHERE s.mno_id = mno_id
   AND (@excludeProfileFilter=true or p.display_name=profile_type OR p.subscription_type=profile_type)
   AND DATE(CONVERT_TZ(s.provisioning_date,"+00:00",timezone)) BETWEEN DATE(CONVERT_TZ(start_date,"+00:00",timezone)) AND DATE(CONVERT_TZ(end_date,"+00:00",timezone))

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    0 As Provisioned, 
    1 As Downloaded,

    CASE WHEN @hourlyReport=TRUE 
        THEN COALESCE(HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(r.end_download_date,"+00:00",timezone)),HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(r.last_update,"+00:00",timezone))) 
        WHEN @monthlyReport=TRUE
        THEN COALESCE(MONTH(CONVERT_TZ(r.end_download_date,"+00:00",timezone)),MONTH(CONVERT_TZ(r.last_update,"+00:00",timezone)))
        ELSE COALESCE(DATE(CONVERT_TZ(r.end_download_date,"+00:00",timezone)),DATE(CONVERT_TZ(r.last_update,"+00:00",timezone)))
    END
    AS DateRange 

   FROM subscription s 
   INNER JOIN profile_type p ON p.id = s.profile_type 
   LEFT JOIN rsp_session r ON r.profile_iccid = s.iccid 
   WHERE s.mno_id = mno_id
   AND (@excludeProfileFilter=TRUE OR p.display_name=profile_type OR p.subscription_type=profile_type)
   AND COALESCE(DATE(CONVERT_TZ(r.end_download_date,"+00:00",timezone)),DATE(CONVERT_TZ(r.last_update,"+00:00",timezone))) BETWEEN DATE(CONVERT_TZ(start_date,"+00:00",timezone)) AND DATE(CONVERT_TZ(end_date,"+00:00",timezone)) AND s.status IN('INSTALLED','ENABLED','DELETED')

) result GROUP BY result.DateRange
) r RIGHT OUTER JOIN tempDates d ON r.DateRange = d.timeRange;

   END;;
   DELIMITER ;
```

The result I am getting in MaroiaDB 10.1.22, which is not the correct one is -

```
2   0   2017-11-02
5   10  2017-11-03
32  16  2017-11-06
51  34  2017-11-07
64  42  2017-11-08
79  47  2017-11-09
79  48  2017-11-10
102 61  2017-11-13
116 61  2017-11-14
128 68  2017-11-15
145 71  2017-11-16
157 82  2017-11-17
196 95  2017-11-20
254 111 2017-11-21
273 118 2017-11-22
313 134 2017-11-23
323 144 2017-11-24
363 149 2017-11-27
368 152 2017-11-28
371 152 2017-11-29
403 160 2017-11-30
403 160 2017-11-01
403 160 2017-11-04
403 160 2017-11-05
403 160 2017-11-11
403 160 2017-11-12
403 160 2017-11-18
403 160 2017-11-19
403 160 2017-11-25
403 160 2017-11-26
```

It should be in order.

Can anyone tell what is the wrong? Or its DB issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "MySQL 10"? Thats not a valid MySQL release

Answer (score 1):

You have no `order by` in any of your queries.  The result set can be in any order, because result sets without an `order by` (like tables) are *unordered* sets.

Hence, the database is correct.  Your understanding is missing this important fact about SQL.

Add the `order by` that you want and the result set will be appropriately ordered in any version of the database that you use.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for reply. I need to call procedure for different durations, like lastMonth, lastYear, lastDay. If I use order By in this - for lastDay I get result like this -

    1
   10
   11
   12
   14
   15
   16
   17
   18
   19
   2
   20
   21
   22
   23
   24
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9